Trying to set up DX APM on JBOSS EAP 7.1 and its failing with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.9
JBoss EAP 7.1.6.GA
Configuration on startup script
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/apps/apm/wily/Agent.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.wily.introscope.agentProfile=/apps/apm/wily/releases/24.3/core/config/IntroscopeAgent.profile"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:${JBOSS_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar"
Exception on startup :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/Level
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
          at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:329)
          at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.Level
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
          at org.jboss.modules.JDKSpecific.getSystemClass(JDKSpecific.java:183)
          at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:397)
          at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)


I have been trying to update the start up script with multiple recommendations I found online

This is easier on EAP 7.4 using the MODULE_OPTS environment variable. That said, you might be missing some other dependencies from the bootclasspath. You likely also need wildfly-commons*.jar.

Hi, it worked when I removed the Xbootclasspath from the startup script and added to the host-master.
